# Is describing someone as “higher-educated” awkward?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

I’m updating my résumé and would like to convey in a condensed manner the fact that I have a Masters degree in a particular branch of the humanities (politics and society of the Middle East, but that’s not necessarily relevant).

I completed the program in 2006, though, and have gained a good bit of professional and field experience since then, so it sounds kind of wrong to refer to myself as *a recent postgraduate* even though that’s actually a nice, punchy formulation of the concept I’d like to convey . . . if only it was recent!

Then again, calling myself *a postgraduate* might not be fair because it could connote that I’m currently undertaking study, which is not the case at all.

I could call myself *higher-educated*, but that just sounds awkward and contrived to me. What do others think about that phrase? Can you think of any alternatives?

Comment: This is a little broad - exactly how small of a space do you have?  It wouldn't take too long to say that you "have a Master's degree in a particular branch of the humanities", would it?

Comment: I would say that you are simply a 'graduate', since as you say, 'post-graduate' suggests that you are continuing your study.

Comment: @drɱ65 δ I'm trying to sum up myself in about 15 words, so I need to be concise. This is for the "tagline" of my resume.

Comment: @mark: Could you let me know why your résumé [here](http://markellison.org/#resume) doesn't fit the bill?

Comment: Because that's the online version and I'm creating a print-ready PDF for more traditional application processes.

Comment: The need for super-condensed resumes is almost gone.  The idea before, was that a hirer had a stack of resumes to go through, and spent only a small amount of time on each, so you want to convey as much in as small a space as possible.  One page used to be the metric.  That's changing a lot, and resumes are starting to be predominantly mined for keywords by computers.  I think it's still nice to have a short resume, but I would recommend two.  One short for handing to people in person, and one that is wordy and detailed for submitting online.

Comment: Thanks @Mark T that's good advice. The remainder of the resume will be plenty wordy. The purpose of this question is craft a concise "tagline" for myself that's descriptive and perhaps memorable.

Comment: Describing someone as "higher-educated" is a good joke. Use it when you introduce the Dean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think that "a recent postgraduate" is perfectly acceptable and accurate.  It demonstrates that you have a recent accomplishment that you are proud of.  It is a selling point.  I think you have a few more years where recent will be an acceptable adjective.

When an interviewer reads a resume they sometimes look for things they can challenge to try and throw you off.  Using terms that sound smooth and sly but are vague and subjective provides them with just the fodder they are looking for.  There is no right answer to "So what exactly does Highly Educated mean?"

Alternately you could simply state that you have a graduate degee.  However being out of school for five years if you have the accomplishments in the professional world to rely on them you could move past your degree.  You education should be on your resume already and your prospective employers can already see your achievement.  Use your tag line to express your abilities as a professional rather than as a student.

Comment: Thank you Chad. I have taken your advice and others' and have nearly settled on the wording: "Multi-disciplinarian digital strategist with an active interest in using connection technologies to address today’s global challenges."

Comment: Ohh an MDDSAICTATGC good choice :)

Comment: Yeah, not too many of those out there :P

Answer (score 0):

A "smoother" American English term than higher-educated is "highLY educated."

That describes the fact that you have a "high" level of education, without implying "higher than you."

Comment: That sounds rather pompous and presumptous and I think calls for a comparison with the reader to thier own. Resume's are already being judged by the interview, a subjective statement like this asks to be challenged. If you feel you are and can stand up to the statement being challenged in an interview that may work for you.

Comment: @Chad good point, thank you. I'll take that into consideration. One option is to leave this part out of the summary altogether and let the reader judge for him or herself how "high" my education is.

Comment: I disagree with Tom's answer.  "Highly" is relative, and you're basically assuming something about the reader.  If you have a masters and you tell a group of PhDs you are "highly educated", they'll laugh.  Conversely, if you have a PhD and you tell people you are "highly educated", they'll think you're being an ass.

Comment: I said that "highLY educated" was "smoother" than the other term. I did NOT say that it was a "good" term.  It's not great, but apparently it was "good enough" for the OP (as of his first comment).

Answer (score 0):

*Higher-educated* sounds wrong. You might be *better*-educated (comparative), or *well*-educated (declarative).

*Higher* is usually prefixed with *education* or *studies*. For example, you might say that you went to Scotland in for your higher education.